# Nonvanishing of Jacobians implies global injectivity?

Tags: reference-request, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-topology, matrices

I am interested in obtaining injectivity of a $C^1$ map from the nonvanishing minors of its Jacobian matrix. Here is a brief history of the topic.

In 1953, [Samuelson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paul_Samuelson) asked the following:

> If the upper left-hand principal minors of the Jacobian matrix of a map $F: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ do not vanish, is it true that $F$ must be injective?

In 1965, [Gale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Gale) and Nikaido gave a counterexample in $\mathbb{R}^2$. In [their paper](http://www.springerlink.com/content/w007438g2kw60qjt/) the following is proved

> **Gale-Nikaido theorem:** If all the principal minors of the Jacobian matrix of $F: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ are **positive**, then $F$ is injective.

Since then, some effort has been made to weaken the assumption in Gale-Nikaido theorem since the assumption seems to be too restrictive in application. A comprehensive dicussion can be found in T. Parthasarathy, *On Global Univalence Theorems*, Lecture Notes in Mathematics, Vol. 977, 1983. In the case of polynomial map, this is related to the real version of [Jacobian conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_conjecture).

A possible generalization I'm interested in is the following, which seems to be open.

> **Question:** If all the principal minors of the Jacobian matrix of $F: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ **do not vanish**, is $F$ necessarily injective?

In Gale and Nikaido's paper, the case of $\mathbb{R}^2$ was answered in affirmative, the case of $\mathbb{R}^3$ was claimed in affirmative (yet no complete proof seems to be known).

My motivation comes from trying to make a change of variables to globally rectify a curved coordinate system so that Plancherel theorem can be applied. Any information would be appreciated : )

Comment: @Syang: You may also want to take a look at *Zorich Theorem* (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zorich's_theorem): If $f: {\mathbb R}^n\to {\mathbb R}^n$ is a locally-injective quasiregular map, then, for $n\ge 3$, the map $f$ is a homeomorphism. A smooth map $f$ is $K$-quasiregular if $||Df(x)||^n\le K |J_f(x)|$ for all $x\in {\mathbb R}^n$. The assumptions are somewhat different from the ones you are asking, but the conclusion is the same.   

Comment: @Misha: Thank you. Zorich's theorem and the results on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasiregular_map are very impressive. Unfortunately the maps I am concerned with are not quasiregular. Their Jocobians collapse when two coordinates coincide whereas their gradients do not.

Comment: The link to `springerlink.com` is broken, but the article can be found at [doi:10.1007/BF01360282](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01360282) or at [EuDML](https://eudml.org/doc/182673) ([Zbl 0158.04903](https://zbmath.org/0158.04903)).

Answer (score 4):

You might be interested by C. Soulé, M.Kaufman, R.Thomas [results](https://www.ihes.fr/%7Esoule/publications.html) (search "multistationarity"). This might seem unrelated to your question but it is in fact related.

Briefly, they study various *necessary* conditions for a differential equation $dx/dt=F(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ to have *several* non degenerate stationary points $F(x)=0$.

The conditions depend on a signed "interaction graph" $G(x)$ deduced from the signs in the Jacobian matrix of $F$ at $x$.

By taking the contrapositive, applied to $F-c$ or various other simple transform , you obtain *sufficient* conditions for $F$ to be injective (assuming non-vanishing jacobian determinant).

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is interesting. But their results don't seem to go beyond the Gale-Nikaido theorem. Maybe I'm missing something, it seems all the sufficient conditions they obtained (in term of properties of graphs associated to the Jacobian) guarantee injectivity via G-N theorem.

Comment: Sure, but the obtained criteria seem more diverse than the one in G-N. 

Answer (score 0):

The answer is NO. Consider the two-dimensional example $F=(f,g)$ with
$$
f(x,y) = \sqrt{2}e^{x/2}\cos(ye^{-x})
$$
$$
g(x,y) = \sqrt{2}e^{x/2}\sin(ye^{-x})
$$
The determinant of the Jacobian matrix is 1 at all points $(x,y)$ 
in the plane. However, $f(0, 2\pi)=f(0,0)$ and $g(0,2\pi)=g(0,0)$,
hence the map $F=(f,g)$ is not injective. It is still an open question 
(the Keller Jacobian Conjecture, 1939) if a *polynomial* map $F:C^n\rightarrow C^n$ 
whose Jacobian determinant is identically 1 is injective.

Comment: Marc, the first principal minor in the Jacobian of $F$ is just the $x$-derivative of $f(x,y)$, and I don't believe that this quantity is non-vanishing. If you evaluate the derivative as a function of $y$ at $x=0$ for instance, it vanishes whenever $\tan(y) = \frac{1}{2y}$.